# Scrubbing IPv4 dotted-quad addresses in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip-address, ipv4

Given a table containing dotted quad IPv4 addresses stored as a `VARCHAR(15)`, for example:

```
     ipv4
--------------
 172.16.1.100
 172.16.50.5
 172.30.29.28
```

what's a convenient way to `SELECT` all `"ipv4"` fields with the final two octets scrubbed, so that the above would become:

```
    ipv4
------------
 172.16.x.y
 172.16.x.y
 172.30.x.y
```

Target RDBMS is postgresql 8.4, but the more portable the better!

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** while I do appreciate (and do upvote) slick `INET`/`CIDR` answers, I am looking to produce a *string* output with non-numeric characters substituted for the final two octets.  (And, again, the more portable the better!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For postgres:

```
select regexp_replace('172.16.1.100', E'(.\\d+){2}$', '.x.y');
```

Comment: my postgres told me to write it as select regexp_replace('172.16.1.100', E'(.\\d+){2}$', '.x.y');

Comment: +1.  This is kindred to, but a clear improvement on, my original approach, which was:  `SUBSTRING("ipv4" FROM E'^(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.){2})') || 'x.y'`  Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a regex when you don't need one. Just use the propper network functions and operators.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Postgres inet type, then you can do this with the inet operators, eg. `<<=` means 'is contained within'. I suspect that something lik the following will do what you need:

```
select my_ipaddress & inet '255.255.0.0' from my_ip_table;
```

Manual reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-net.html

Answer (score 1):

Conventional is to convert column type to [inet/cidr](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/datatype-net-types.html)

EDIT:
With this native data type there's quite a few [specific](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-net.html) functions that perform much better than any string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, goran.  In fact the source records are INET type.  But how would this help me to conceal the last two octets?  (Seems to me I need to convert to a string-type and munge from there.)